# Comparar que una hora esté en un rango JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un método que te calcula si una hora que le pasas como string está en un rango de horas que tu le das, pero me gustaría saber si puedo optimizarlo, ya que mi codigo es un conjunto de comprobaciones por todos lados.

Tampoco me funciona que cuando introduces una hora inválida lance la excepción y siempre imprime false.

```js
function compareTime(time, initTime, endTime) {
try {
    return ((parseInt(time.split(":")[0]) >= parseInt(initTime.split(":")[0]) && parseInt(time.split(":")[1]) >= parseInt(initTime.split(":")[1]))
        && (parseInt(time.split(":")[0]) < parseInt(endTime.split(":")[0]) && parseInt(time.split(":")[1]) < parseInt(endTime.split(":")[1])));
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
}

function checkTime(time) {
if ((parseInt(time.split(":")[0]) > 23 && parseInt(time.split(":")[0]) < 0)
    && (parseInt(time.split(":")[1]) > 59 && parseInt(time.split(":")[1]) < 0)) {
    throw new Error("Invalid Time")
}
return time;
}

let time1 = "15:10";
let time2 = "23:59";
let time3 = "20:65";

console.log(compareTime(time1, "00:00", "18:25")); //True
console.log(compareTime(time2, "00:00", "18:25")); //False
console.log(compareTime(time3, "00:00", "18:25")); //Throws exception
```

Lo que no quiero es tener que hacer `split(":")` todo el tiempo.
Habría alguna forma de mejorar el código?
Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesitas usar [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) ni tampoco convertir los valores a números, mucho menos crear Clases ni nada complejo.

La comparación de valores de cadena con los operadores `>`, `>=`, `<` y `<=` se realiza de forma lexicográfica, por lo cual, al ser las cadenas que manejas de tipo incremental, podrías compararlas directamente. Lo único que debes realmente comprobar en cada cadena introducida es que su valor en minutos no sea superior a 59. De resto las comparaciones son directas.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const inicio = '03:10';
const fin = '18:25';
const horas = [
  '01:15',
  '18:26',
  '09:11',
  '03:11',
  '18:25',
  '03:09',
  '24:13',
  '10:60'
];

const isInRange = (start, end, time) => {
  if(time < '00:00' || time > '23:59' || time.substring(3) > '59') {
    console.log('Hora no válida');
    return;
    // o throw new Error('Hora no válida');
  }
  return time >= start && time <= end;
}

horas.forEach(hora => {
  console.log(isInRange(inicio, fin, hora));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como puedes observar, te devuelve `true` sólo si la hora está dentro del rango, `false` en caso contrario y un mensaje de error si la hora no es válida.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Si que ayuda muchas gracias, lo único, ¿por que la antepenúltima hora da como resultado undefined? 03:09 si que es una hora válida, ¿no?
Sobre todo porque la cuarta hora es 2 minutos antes y devuelve true

Comment: No, las 2 últimas horas son inválidas. Primero sale el log interno de la función ('Hora inválida!) y luego el log del `return` de la llamada a la función (`undefined` porque no devuelve ni `true` ni `false`). Saludos

Comment: Excelente solución, pero me queda la duda que pasa si colocas por ejemplo const inicio = '//'   ?   o si ingresas como una hora '3:00'  ??

Comment: Pues en ese caso no funcionaría, en ningún momento se espera que las cadenas recibidas tengan un formato distinto a `'hh:mm'`, donde `hh` y `mm` sean valores numéricos del `00` al `99`.

Comment: Aaaahh entiendo, aunque el error de los formatos es facil de solucionar, solo hay que concatenar un 0 a la izquierda si el valor es inferior a 10 y listo

Comment: Y aunque no tenga mucho que ver con el propio problema, que es lo que hace ```.as-console-wrapper``` ??

Comment: @GreenLass Para que la consola ocupe todo el alto

Comment: `.as-console-wrapper` efectivamente es la clase CSS del componente que muestra la consola del *snippet* de [es.so]. Ciertamente la modifico para que abarque todo el alto disponible. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Yo pasé todo a una clase Tiempo, creo que trabajarlo así es más cómodo (pensando en futuros cambios)

A mí la mejora obvia a tu código es pasar todo a "hora militar", ejemplo las 13:34 sería un entero 1334, con ello ya no tienes que comparar el tiempo hora a hora minuto a minuto: 1234>2200 es más fácil que 12>22 && 34>0

Y si te fijas bien en mi código, que a primera vista puede parecer más largo, pero no existe ese enredo de condiciones del if

```js
class Tiempo{
  constructor(horastring){
    try{
        let h = horastring.split(":");
        this.hora = Number(h[0]);
        this.minutos = Number(h[1]);
        this.militarhora = this.hora * 1000 + this.minutos;
    }
    catch{
       throw new Error("Invalid Time");
    }
     
     if( !this.chekrange(this.hora,24) || !this.chekrange(this.minutos,60)){
        throw new Error("Invalid Time")
     }
  }
  chekrange(t,max){
    return t>=0 && t<max;
  }
  isDentroDelItervalo(initTime, endTime){
    let hi = new Tiempo(initTime);
    let hf = new Tiempo(endTime);
    return this.militarhora>=hi.militarhora && this.militarhora<=hf.militarhora;
    
  }
}


let time1 = "13:10";
let time2 = "23:59";
let time3 = "20:65";

console.log(new Tiempo(time1).isDentroDelItervalo("00:00", "18:25")); //True
console.log(new Tiempo(time2).isDentroDelItervalo("00:00", "18:25")); //True
console.log(new Tiempo(time3).isDentroDelItervalo("asd:00", "18:25")); //Error
```

Comment: Entiendo, si que habia pensado en usar un objeto para controlarlo o controlarlo desde la clase Date, pero no habia pensado en cómo implementarlo... Lo único en tu codigo si pones como hora "36:10" te lo acepta como válido, aunque no entre en el rango, pero eso es facil de arreglar, gracias!

Comment: @GreenLass Tienes razón. Corregido

Answer (score -1):

Optimiza cargando variables con las posibles funciones que repites algo así:

```
let time1 = "15:10";
let time2 = "23:59";

function compareTime(time, initTime, endTime) {
     var datoCheckTime = checkTime(time);
     if (datoCheckTime == null || datoCheckTime == null || datoCheckTime == null)
        return null;
     else {
        var elParse0 = parseInt(time.split(":")[0];
        var elParse1 = parseInt(time.split(":")[1];
        return elParse0 >= elParse0 && elParse1 >= elParse1
        && elParse0 < elParse0 && elParse1 < elParse1
}
```

}

```
function checkTime(time) {
    var elParse0 = parseInt(time.split(":")[0];
    var elParse1 = parseInt(time.split(":")[1];
    return elParse0 > 23 && elParse0 < 0
    && elParse1 > 59 && elParse0 ? null : time;
}

console.log(compareTime(time1, "00:00", "18:25")); //True
console.log(compareTime(time2, "00:00", "18:25")); //False
```

Comment: pero en tu código nunca compruebas initTime y endTime, si te fijas he actualizado la pregunta porque me di cuenta de algunos errores que tenía

Comment: Has cambiado del todo la pregunta, en tu antiguo código esta respuesta podía ser  valida ya que en el único punto donde aplicabas el tiempo se podía optimizar de este modo. 
Con los nuevos datos, quizas no haya forma de optimizar tu código.